# Other method show that $ A(x)=x^2+x+1=0$ has a zeros in $\mathbb{R}$ but why this contradiction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $ A(x)=x^2+x+1$  be a quadratic polynomial equation and $ x \in\mathbb{R}$. It is well known that $ A(x)=x^2+x+1=0$ hasn't a roots in $\mathbb {R}$ , we choose another way to solve this equation in $\mathbb{R}$ .

We have $ A(x)=x^2+x+1=0 $ and $x \in\mathbb{R}$ $$\implies  x^2= -(x+1)\tag{1}$$

And we could rewrite $A(x)$ as this form :$$A(x)=x^2+x+1=x(x+1)+1=0 \tag{2}$$

We replace the $(x+1)$ by $-x^2$ from $(1)$ in $(2)$ we obtain the following equation:

$$x^3=1 \implies x=1,$$ then the zero of $A(x)=0$ is $x=1$ in $\mathbb {R}$ .

I'm confused for one thing, does $x=1$ rejected solution as it's not in $(-\infty,-1]$ or there are others reasons ?

Thank you for any help .

Comment: what does $x²= -(x+1)....(1)$ mean? Similarly, $0.....(2)$?

Comment: @SamuelYusim If $x^2+(x+1)=0$ than $x^2=-(x+1)$

Comment: oh, you're labelling your equation. I see.

Comment: my problem , why it's has a zero with this method , where is the problem in my method that i wondred ?

Comment: @user51189 Well you proved that if for some $t$ we have that $A(t)=0$ than you have that $t^3-1=0$ but that doesn't imply that if $b^3-1=0$ than $A(b)=0$ for some $b$

Comment: I'm seeking for the problem in my method

Comment: @kingW3 : see well my question ?

Comment: I see your question,you should re read my comment,or in notation $A(t)=0\implies t^3=1$ but $t^3=1\not \Rightarrow A(t)=0$

Comment: @kingW3: do you mean it's not equivalence ?

Comment: Yes it is not equivalence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19457/discussion-between-kingw3-and-user51189).

Answer (score 4):

You have proved that $x^2 + x + 1 = 0 \implies x^3 = 1$.  This is a nice fact, but it doesn't contradict the statement that the second equation has real solutions while the first one doesn't.

One way to look at this is the factorization $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$.  Clearly, the right-hand side vanishes when $x=1$, but that tells us nothing about $x^2 + x + 1$ (which, of course, doesn't vanish).

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of logic. "If it is raining then the sidewalk is wet", it does not follow that, "if the sidewalk is wet then it is raining". This is called *fallacy of the converse*.

You showed that if $A(x)$ has a solution then $x=1$. This does not mean that $x=1$ must be a solution.

Comment: @kingW3:Thank you, look $x \in\mathbb{R}$ after $x $ should be in $(-\infty,-1]$ , but this always used in inequality not in equation for justification to accept or reject solutions

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not an equivalence but is just implication so the contradiction is because $A(1)=3\not=0$ and because $x\not\in(-\infty,-1]$

Comment: thank you, the problem is:  Always   $x\not\in(-\infty,-1]$. is formula used in inequality for justification not in equations FOR justification .